# How install wxpython with python3 in linux?, gives me error

Tags: wxpython, python-3.6, libjpeg

**Error**

> checking for GL/gl.h... no
>       configure: error: OpenGL libraries not available
>       Error running configure
>       ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "build.py", line 1321, in cmd_build_wx
>           wxbuild.main(wxDir(), build_options)
>         File "/tmp/pip-build-1v9li5h1/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line
>   375, in main
>           "Error running configure")
>         File "/tmp/pip-build-1v9li5h1/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line
>   85, in exitIfError
>           raise builder.BuildError(msg)
>       buildtools.builder.BuildError: Error running configure
>       Finished command: build_wx (0m5.163s)
>       Finished command: build (0m5.163s)
>       Command '"/usr/bin/python3" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1v9li5h1/wxpython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nsn2w9dk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1v9li5h1/wxpython/
```

**~ » python3**

```
XXX-PC
Python 3.6.5 (default, May 11 2018, 13:30:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 import sys
 import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *
```

> ImportError: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Answer (score 2):

I usually do the following:

```
pip3 install wxPython
```

If that does not work, then you may not have one of wxPython's dependencies installed:

- https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/README.rst#prerequisites

I have noticed on Ubuntu that I sometimes need to install webkit, opengl, etc to get wxPython to install. Your error message even mentions OpenGL as missing, so I would start there.

Comment: thanks for you help, my problem is with spyder, :( , in terminal is ok.

Comment: I haven't used that IDE. Sorry

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Thanks for the link - installing all dependencies listed on that GitHub readme page solved a similar issue with `wxPython` installation via `pip` for me.